# dropdown disabled in table asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i try to disable dropdown in table.. like when admin view any new documents and then select value from dropdown i.e aprove/reject when he select and click on button then this dropdown must be disabled and then when amdin again view new documents then in this dropdown must bt enable until admin approve/reject this document .....how i done this ..

```
      protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {



        DropDownList ddldrop = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList4") as DropDownList;
        HiddenField hfDepartmentId = e.Item.FindControl("hfDepartmentId") as 
         HiddenField;

        if (ddldrop != null && hfDepartmentId != null) 
        {
            if(hfDepartmentId.Value != string.Empty && hfDepartmentId.Value.Trim() != 
               "3")
            {


            ddldrop.SelectedValue = hfDepartmentId.Value.Trim();
            ddldrop.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, but did it work? If not, what was the problem?

Comment: it cannot work .it disable all drop downs and i want when new documents comes in table then this row drop down must be enable still admin take action in it like admin approve/reject

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to enable if the departID is "3" but you don't have an `else` in your `if`. Here is a shortened and simplified version of your approach:

```
protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropDownList ddldrop = (DropDownList) e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList4");
        HiddenField hfDepartmentId = (HiddenField) e.Item.FindControl("hfDepartmentId");
        ddldrop.Enabled = hfDepartmentId.Value == "3";
        if(ddldrop.Enabled) ddldrop.SelectedValue = hfDepartmentId.Value;
    }
}
```

Note that i've checked the `ListItemType` which makes your null-reference check redundant. You should also  use more menaingful names for your controls, i would suggest `DdlDepartment` instead of `DropDownList4`.

Comment: it cannot work .it disable all drop downs and i want when new documents comes in table then this row drop down must be enable still admin take action in it like admin approve/reject